# WARNING: The OpenGL rendering context obtained on X display

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, opengl

I've installed bumblebee with this tutorial
http://eternalvoid.net/tutorials/linux-optimus-gt650m/

and when I try optirun i've got black screen & this:

```
$ optirun glxspheres
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x21
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":8".
[VGL] WARNING: The OpenGL rendering context obtained on X display
[VGL]    :8 is indirect, which may cause performance to suffer.
[VGL]    If :8 is a local X display, then the framebuffer device
[VGL]    permissions may be set incorrectly.
Context is Indirect
OpenGL Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
[VGL] ERROR: OpenGL error 0x0500
[VGL] ERROR: in readpixels--
[VGL]    310: Could not Read Pixels
```

Lenovo y580, Ubuntu 12.04 x64, NVIDIA ver.driver 319.17

It's a problem with driver, configuration or something else?

Comment: Does that also happen, if you run **sudo optirun glxspheres**?

Answer (score 0):

I GUESS, it is a problem with the nvidia driver. Reading the link you posted, on how you installed bumblebee, I see that you installed the nvidia driver manually. My suggestion is to change runlevel by pressing:

STRG + ALT + f6

then stop the window-manager

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

and uninstall the nvidia driver

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia
```

Since you have already added the swat-x-repos, you should then be able after restarting to install nvidia again from the repositories following step 1 and 2 again and then typing

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 bumblebee-nvidia
```

Hope that helps.